# How to detach event handlers from HtmlElement objects? c#

Tags: c#, html, events, event-handling

first of all, I'm new to this forum and relatively new to programming. 
My problem is that I can't detach event handlers attached previously. At least, DetachEventHandler in the following code doesn't do it:

```
private void addHandlersToElement(HtmlElement thiselement)
{
        thiselement.DetachEventHandler("onclick", delegate { myClickHandler(thiselement, EventArgs.Empty); });
        thiselement.AttachEventHandler("onclick", delegate { myClickHandler(thiselement, EventArgs.Empty); });
}
```

It obviously doesn't work because the code in the event handler executes as many times as I called  *addHandlersToElements*, that is, attach works but detach doesn't.

The truth is that I don't know very much about delegates, just that they are wrappers for methods to make it possible to pass them as parameters. This *delegate{}* block I stole from some post, because this seemed the only solution to work for passing *thiselement* as the sender object (which I'm referring to in my actual handler method). Using

```
new EventHandler(myMouseoverEventHandler)
```

for parameter actually works, but then, AFAIK, I cannot pass the sender.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will solve the problem if you assign the delegate to a reference, like this:

```
var del = delegate { myClickHandler(thiselement, EventArgs.Empty); };
```

and then attach and detach the same delegate object instead of attaching one delegate and detaching another:

```
thiselement.AttachEventHandler("onclick", del);
thiselement.DetachEventHandler("onclick", del);
```

Comment: It's important that I have to use the detach first. I only want to detach the PREVIOUSLY attached delegate so that they don't accumulate on my htmlelement. 
I applied your snippet like this:

            d = delegate {myClickHandler(thiselement);};
            thiselement.DetachEventHandler("onclick", d);
            thiselement.AttachEventHandler("onclick", d);
But it won't work. The detached delegate is different from the last one added.

Comment: You must hold a reference to the attached delegate somewhere. After you attach it, don't let it get lost like you're doing now.